# strange noise in some gui programs

Tags: debian, drivers, libraries, graphics

I have Debian testing, I use XFCE. Recently, shortly after dist-upgrade, I noticed that XFCE terminal has some noise in it - especially near the end of long lines or when I use midnight commander. The noise looks like that:

[image]

I started using gnome-terminal instead and problem disappeared.

Now I noticed I have similar problem with GIMP - the toolbox contains noise instead of tools:

[image]

I can't even guess where should I start investigation. Is it problem with GIMP, XFCE, GTK, X, hardware? Or something else? I tried to start raw X, without any window manager (without Gnome, without XFCE etc) and problem is still the same - so I guess it's not X's fault.

What do you advice?

Comment: I would guess your X graphics card driver. Which driver are you using? Which video card do you have?

Comment: Maybe broken libs, I've experienced similar stuff when librsvg is upgraded in Gentoo, and chromium got wired background image as well, try upgrade everything with `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade` first